# strtok not going through all tokens

Tags: c, linux, shell, strtok

I'm trying to implement a shell as part of a school assignment, and I'm stuck on the file input/output redirection part.

More specifically, I've come up with a function which allows me to detect whether or not the command entered in specifies a '>' or '<' or even a '|'.

Ideally, if I enter `ls -a > ls.tx`', then the tokens `ls -a` and `ls.txt` should be returned.

My code doesn't do this, it only returns `ls -a` then stops.

My code is below:

```
/*commandLine is a char* taken in from the user, and is a null-terminated string */
int counter = 0;
parsedLine = strtok(commandLine, ">");
while (parsedLine != NULL)
{
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        strncpy(parsedCpy, parsedLine, strlen(parsedLine));
        parseCommand(parsedCpy, commands);
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        redirect->re_stdout = parsedLine;
    }
    parsedLine = strtok(NULL, ">");
}
```

I've tried it in another test file just to see if there was something wrong, but this test file (code below) returns the expected result (that is, `ls -a` and `ls.txt`)

```
    char myString[] = "ls -a > ls.txt";
char* parsed;

parsed = strtok(myString, ">");
while (parsed != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", parsed);
    parsed = strtok(NULL, ">");
}
```

Is there something that I'm just not understanding? I don't really see where I'm going wrong, since the code itself is nearly the same in both cases.

Comment: Note that `strncpy` won't zero terminate a string unless the zero termination is part of the source being copied. See `man strncpy`. It says: *Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in  dest  will  not  be null-terminated.* That could be horsing something else up depending upon what `parseCommand` does.

Comment: Your problem lies elsewhere. Here's a modified version that works just fine: http://ideone.com/WLfQER

Comment: You should just do a `strcpy`. A `strncpy` doesn't really do anything for you if you're giving it the length of the source string, unless you're intentionally trying to avoid copying the null terminator. `strcpy(parsedCpy, parsedLine);`

Comment: @mbratch - Your comments are worthy of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `strncpy` won't zero terminate a string unless the zero termination is part of the source being copied. See `man strncpy`. It says:

> **Warning:** If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

That could be horsing something else up depending upon what parseCommand does.

In this case, you should just do a `strcpy`. A `strncpy` doesn't really do anything for you if you're giving it the length of the source string, unless you're intentionally trying to avoid copying the null terminator. So you should use, `strcpy(parsedCpy, parsedLine);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

That turned out to be the answer that I was looking for! The non-null erminated string was doing some crazy things after it was passed onto parseCommand

Answer (score 0):

***I cannot see how  parsedLine is declared***, but it needs to be handled explicitly and carefully.  i.e. make sure the pointer to that value is not changed except by `strtok()`, and make sure that it remains null terminated.  One thing I do when using `strtok()` for multiple calls, is to use an intermediate value to collect results, helping to keep the target buffer pure and unchanged except by `strtok()`

***A small code snippet to illustrate:***

```
char a[] = {"ls -a > ls.tx"};
char *buff;
char keep[80];

buff = strtok(a, ">");
    strcpy(keep, buff);
buff = strtok(NULL, ">");
    strcat(keep, buff);
```

This usage of `strtok()` is clean, i.e. it does not allow buff to be affected except by another call to `strtok()`

***By comparison***, this section of your code is a little scary because I do not know the output of the `strncpy()` which depends so heavily on the third argument, and can corrupt (place unexpected results into) parseCommand :

```
if (counter == 0)
{
    strncpy(parsedCpy, parsedLine, strlen(parsedLine));
    parseCommand(parsedCpy, commands);
    counter++;
}
else
{
    redirect->re_stdout = parsedLine;
}
parsedLine = strtok(NULL, ">");
```

***Along the lines*** of keeping the target buffer pure, (*even though it does not appear to be an issue here*), `strtok()` is not thread safe.  If a function using `strtok()` is used in a multi threaded process, the target buffer is subject to any number of calls, resulting in unexpected, and perhaps even undefined behavior.    In this case using `strtok_r()` is a better option